# Show list item column value in search result web part

Tags: list, search-results

When items like a Word doc or PDF is shown in the Search Result Web Part, it shows the:

1. Name (which is the link)
2. A bit of content from the doc (first few lines)
3. Path location

I have another Search Result Web Part only displaying list items from a specific list,
which only shows number 1 and 3

- List item (Title)
- Path location

Is it possible to show some values of the list item columns with the result in the web part? (e.g. Description and Cost column values)

Haven't had much luck on Google. Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You should use Bing! :) What you need to learn is how to change a Display Template (for search results) and Client Side Rendering (CSR is for Lists and Libraries).

There are a bunch of tutorials that walk through the steps:

1. Use Design Manager to access the Display Templates
2. Copy an existing Display Template that is close to what you want
3. Add the fields that you want to see
4. Edit the template to look like you want
5. Deploy the template
6. Create a Result Type rule for it to show.

You can see a how to here: http://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2013/06/05/introduction-to-sharepoint-2013-display-templates/